# Is there a way to detect KeyPress events in address bar AND document body in Google Chrome Extensions?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I'm trying to write a chrome extension that plays a sound every time a key is pressed in the browser (whether that's inside the document of a website, in the chrome address bar, or in about:blank). I'm trying to find something in the Chrome Extension API to get an eventlistener or something I can attach an event listener to. Does such a thing exist?

Initially, I tried just injecting the following into content scripts of every website I came across.

```js
document.addEventListener("keypress", () => {
    //Insert sound playing code here
});
```

However, the event listener did not fire for about:blank and when typing in the chrome address bar.

I then tried using chrome.input.ime. However, it apparently doesn't work (deprecated?) for manifest v3.

I also tried Chrome omnibox as the comment below suggested, but that doesn't really solve the problem since I want to detect keypress within the entire chromium browser (and not just the address bar) and because the omnibox API only works on certain keywords typed in the address bar when I want to detect any keypress.

Comment: No, but there's [chrome.omnibox](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/omnibox) API can be used after the user types a keyword of your extension in the address bar.